# can't pass a newtype-wrapped unsafe C struct without causing illegal instruction

Tags: rust, ffi

I am working on wrapping the unsafe FFI layer [here](https://github.com/tupshin/cql-ffi/), and am running into a very strange problem. (Latest nightly)

```
extern crate cql_ffi;
use std::ffi::CString;

#[allow(missing_copy_implementations)]
pub struct CassCluster(pub cql_ffi::CassCluster);

fn main() {

    let cluster = &mut CassCluster(unsafe{*cql_ffi::cass_cluster_new()});
    println!("trying method 1");
    let result1 = method1();

    println!("trying method 2");
    let result2 = method2(cluster);
}

pub fn method1() {
    let cluster = &mut CassCluster(unsafe{*cql_ffi::cass_cluster_new()});    
    let result = unsafe{cql_ffi::cass_cluster_set_contact_points(&mut cluster.0,  CString::from_slice("127.0.0.1".as_bytes()).as_ptr() as *const i8)};
}

pub fn method2(cluster: &mut CassCluster) {
    let result = unsafe{cql_ffi::cass_cluster_set_contact_points(&mut cluster.0,  CString::from_slice("127.0.0.1".as_bytes()).as_ptr() as *const i8)};
}
```

Note that method 1 and 2 only differ in whether the cluster was passed in to the fn or created inside of it.

When run:

```
trying method 1
trying method 2
Illegal instruction
```

Whether or not method1 is called, method2 always fails with an illegal instruction.

The valgrind produced stacktrace might be interesting:

```
trying method 2
==19145== Invalid write of size 8
==19145==    at 0x6A10ACF: std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==19145==    by 0x4F78367: std::list<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::_M_insert(std::_List_iterator<std::string>, std::string const&) (in /usr/local/lib/libcassandra.so.1.0.0.rc1)
==19145==    by 0x4F77E13: std::list<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::push_back(std::string const&) (in /usr/local/lib/libcassandra.so.1.0.0.rc1)
==19145==    by 0x4F8AE69: cass_cluster_set_contact_points (in /usr/local/lib/libcassandra.so.1.0.0.rc1)
==19145==    by 0x10DDC3: method2::h2b76fca37ae2e2878ba (test.rs:25)
==19145==    by 0x10DA1B: main::hc39cc26c65e20849maa (test.rs:13)
==19145==    by 0x11C198: rust_try_inner (in /home/tupshin/workspaces/rust/cql-ffi-safe/target/test)
==19145==    by 0x11C185: rust_try (in /home/tupshin/workspaces/rust/cql-ffi-safe/target/test)
==19145==    by 0x11988C: rt::lang_start::hd3d7c7415c447b9fdBB (in /home/tupshin/workspaces/rust/cql-ffi-safe/target/test)
==19145==    by 0x10DC04: main (in /home/tupshin/workspaces/rust/cql-ffi-safe/target/test)
==19145==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Comment: Why are you *reading* from the pointer returned by `cass_cluster_new`? From the [README](https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver/), it looks like this constructor is the normal C pattern of returning a pointer to an opaque blob of data. You shouldn't read it, simply pass it around and back to the method(s) that expect it.

Comment: Sorry, I got thrown off by the solution to the ICE that was previously blocking me. I switch this back to just being a dereference, which results in the exact same symptoms. Should that be valid, or do I *have* to the wrap using an &?

Comment: How much experience do you already have with C / C++? That might help me better formulate a good answer.

Comment: Enough to understand the constructs, but not enough to be able to reason about them well. Have dabbled in them here and there over the years, but mostly coming from a java/perl/etc background. I appreciate your efforts. thanks for asking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are going about this from the wrong angle - you should not be dereferencing the pointer that the C library is returning to you. You don't actually even know what the makeup of the pointed-at object is!

Instead, you should simply *keep* the pointer and pass it back to the functions that expect it. I've taken some of your code and reorganized it. Here, we have a struct called `Cluster` which will own the pointer returned by `cass_cluster_new`. We create a small example method that does something interesting to the cluster, and we also deal with freeing our resources when we are done with the `Cluster`.

Note that this `Cluster` struct actually takes up space, as opposed to the empty `Cluster` enum that you currently have. The empty enum takes up **zero** space, and so it's going to be optimized in interesting ways. However, you actually need to keep the pointer *somewhere*!

The other thing is that we simply treat the return pointer from the library as a `c_void`. This is because we are *never* going to dereference it, so we just treat it as an opaque handle.

```
#![feature(libc)]

extern crate libc;

use libc::{c_void,c_int};

extern "C" {
    pub fn cass_cluster_new() -> *mut c_void;
    pub fn cass_cluster_free(cluster: *mut c_void);
    pub fn cass_cluster_set_port(cluster: *mut c_void, port: c_int); // ignoring return code
}

struct Cluster(*mut c_void);

impl Cluster {
    fn new() -> Cluster {
        Cluster(unsafe { cass_cluster_new() })
    }

    // N.B. Ports are better represented as u16! 
    fn set_port(&mut self, port: i32) {
        unsafe { cass_cluster_set_port(self.0, port) }
    }
}

impl Drop for Cluster {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe { cass_cluster_free(self.0) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut cluster = Cluster::new();
    cluster.set_port(5432);

    // cluster is automatically dropped when it goes out of scope
}
```

([Playpen](http://is.gd/n53r85))

Comment: Extremely helpful, thanks. I think this gives me most of the mental tools necessary to progress. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess the fact that bindgen generates
     pub fn cass_cluster_new() -> *mut CassCluster;
instead of 
    pub fn cass_cluster_new() -> *mut c_void;pub fn cass_cluster_new() -> *mut c_void;
means that I have to make the choice to modify the output of bindgen as a form of documentation, or else use the *mut CassCluster but make sure that I'm *only* using it as if it were the c_void opaque blob of your version

Comment: You mentioned that you were using bindgen, which I assume is [this project](https://github.com/crabtw/rust-bindgen). I haven't used it, but my guess is that they use pointers to an empty enum to provide some type-safety for the raw pointers. This is useful when you start having multiple types of raw pointer. The important takeaway is that you shouldn't dereference these pointers yourself - let the native library handle that.

Comment: Said another way, you could have `struct Cluster(*mut CassCluster)` instead of `struct Cluster(*mut c_void)`, and everything would still work out. Just never try to peek inside that pointer! ^_^

Comment: yup..i was trying to say the same thing in my cross comment. makes perfect sense